# Merging of two different json objects

Tags: arrays, postgresql, jsonb

I have a scenario where in i am combine two json objects in a table, where they are stored as two different rows in a table.

The combined json object is formed considering the below points

if a tag is present in the 2nd row, then consider the value of that tag, if it is not present then consider the value of the 1st row.

[image]

Consider only the tags that are present in 1st row.
JSON Data is as Below:

**Row 1 JSON ----------**

```
[
  {
    "key": "service",
    "type": "radio",
    "templateOptions": {
      "label": "Service",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "noService",
          "label": "Do Nothing",
          "color": "green"
        },
        {
          "value": "spin",
          "label": "Spin Cutter",
          "color": "yellow"
        },
        {
          "value": "replace",
          "label": "Replace Cutter",
          "color": "red"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "wear",
    "type": "radio",
    "templateOptions": {
      "label": "Wear",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "w1",
          "label": "Wear 1",
          "color": "orange"
        },
        {
          "value": "w2",
          "label": "Wear 2",
          "color": "#123456"
        },
        {
          "value": "w3",
          "label": "Wear 3",
          "color": "#BBBB00"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

**Row 2 JSON ----------**

```
[
  {
    "key": "service",
    "templateOptions": {
      "label": "서비스",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "noService",
          "label": "아무것도하지 마세요",
          "color": "#330000"
        },
        {
          "value": "spin",
          "label": "스핀 커터",
          "color": "#AA0000"
        },
        {
          "value": "replace",
          "label": "커터 교체",
          "color": "#FF0000"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "wear",
    "templateOptions": {
      "label": "입고 있다",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "w2",
          "color": "#770000"
        },
        {
          "value": "w3",
          "label": "착용 3",
          "color": "#990000"
        },
        {
          "value": "w123",
          "label": "커도하`, color: ‘#440000"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

**COMBINED JSON ----------**

```
[
  {
    "key": "service",
    "type": "radio",
    "templateOptions": {
      "label": "서비스",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "noService",
          "label": "아무것도하지 마세요",
          "color": "#330000"
        },
        {
          "value": "spin",
          "label": "스핀 커터",
          "color": "#AA0000"
        },
        {
          "value": "replace",
          "label": "커터 교체",
          "color": "#FF0000"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "wear",
    "type": "radio",
    "templateOptions": {
      "label": "입고 있다",
      "options": [
        {
          "value": "w1",
          "label": "Wear 1",
          "color": "orange"
        },
        {
          "value": "w2",
          "label": "Wear 2",
          "color": "#770000"
        },
        {
          "value": "w3",
          "label": "착용 3",
          "color": "#990000"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: please copy and paste your json instead of an image.

Comment: Row 1 JSON
----------
[{
key: ‘service’,
type: ‘radio’,
templateOptions: {
label: ‘Service’,
options: [
{ value: ‘noService’, label: ‘Do Nothing’, color: ‘green’}
{ value: ‘spin’, label: ‘Spin Cutter’, color: ‘yellow’}
{ value: ‘replace’, label: ‘Replace Cutter’, color: ‘red’}
]
}
}, {
key: ‘wear’,
type: ‘radio’,
templateOptions: {
label: ‘Wear’,
options: [
{ value: ‘w1’, label: ‘Wear 1’, color: ‘orange’ },
{ value: ‘w2’, label: ‘Wear 2’, color: ‘#123456’ },
{ value: ‘w3’, label: ‘Wear 3’, color: ‘#BBBB00’}
]
}
]

Comment: Row 2 JSON
----------

[{
key: ‘service’,
templateOptions: {
label: ‘서비스’,
options: [
{ value: ‘noService’, label: ‘아무것도하지 마세요’, color: ‘#330000’}
{ value: ‘spin’, label: ‘스핀 커터’, color: ‘#AA0000’}
{ value: ‘replace’, label: ‘커터 교체’, color: ‘#FF0000’}
]
}
}, {
key: ‘wear’,
templateOptions: {
label: ‘입고 있다’,
options: [
{ value: ‘w2’, color: ‘#770000’},
{ value: ‘w3’, label: ‘착용 3’, color: ‘#990000’},
{ value: ‘w123’, label: ‘커도하`, color: ‘#440000’}
]
}
]

Comment: Combined JSON
-------------

[{
key: ‘service’,
type: ‘radio’,
templateOptions: {
label: ‘서비스’,
options: [
{ value: ‘noService’, label: ‘아무것도하지 마세요’, color: ‘#330000’}
{ value: ‘spin’, label: ‘스핀 커터’, color: ‘#AA0000’}
{ value: ‘replace’, label: ‘커터 교체’, color: ‘#FF0000’}
]
}
}, {
key: ‘wear’,
type: ‘radio’,
templateOptions: {
label: ‘입고 있다’,
options: [
{ value: ‘w1’, label: ‘Wear 1’, color: ‘orange’},
{ value: ‘w2’, label: ‘Wear 2’, color: ‘#770000’},
{ value: ‘w3’, label: ‘착용 3’, color: ‘#990000’}
]
}
]

Comment: You should post it in Question